# bash edit-and-execute-command echo

Tags: bash

When I run the following one line loop, I get the expected output.

```
for index in $(seq 1 5) ; do echo "$(date +"%Y%m%d" -d "20160301 $index day")"; done
20160302
20160303
20160304
20160305
20160306
```

But when I use bash's edit-and-execute-command (<kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>) and enter the same one line loop, I get output with unexpected commands echoed throughout.

```
for index in $(seq 1 5) ; do echo "$(date +"%Y%m%d" -d "20160301 $index day")"; done
seq 1 5
date +"%Y%m%d" -d "20160301 $index day"
20160302
date +"%Y%m%d" -d "20160301 $index day"
20160303
date +"%Y%m%d" -d "20160301 $index day"
20160304
date +"%Y%m%d" -d "20160301 $index day"
20160305
date +"%Y%m%d" -d "20160301 $index day"
20160306
```

I have `export EDITOR=vim` in my `.bash_profile`.

---

Update with more complicated example in response to comment from @l'L'l

I am using sub-shells because the real command is doing a fair bit more..

```
for index in $(seq 1 10) ; do td=`date +"%Y%m%d" -d "20160301 $index day"`; echo "$td: $(grep "$td" *gprs.csv | wc -l)" ; done
```

As with the simpler example, pasting into the command line is OK, but using edit-and-execute-command gives lots of echos in between.

I have already moved past this by using a script (because naturally enough the issue became even more complicated), but I am still interested to know if there an easy fix for this (edit-and-execute-command doesn't seem so useful if the output is not clear).

Comment: Perhaps it is setting `set -v` when we invoke editor. As such, they go to `stderr`.

Comment: Remove the `"` around the `date` command: `echo $(date ... );`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: The command is fine, although it's unclear why you need a sub-shell, `do date ...` should work. Tested with `vim`, `emacs`, and `nano` — all output correctly after edit and exec.

Comment: FWIW, "edit-and-execute-command" is bound to `C-x C-e`, not `C-x C-y`.

Comment: @romainl - thanks, corrected.

Comment: Reproduced saying something as simple as `echo "hello"`. The `echo` gets printed but before I see the command to be executed: `echo "hello"`. To me, it makes sense, since it shows you what you are about to execute similarly to what `!!` does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash [turns on the `v` flag](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/fc.def?h=bash-4.4-rc2#n463) before evaluating contents of the [temporary file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/fc.def?h=bash-4.4-rc2#n394):

```
/* Turn on the `v' flag while fc_execute_file runs so the commands
   will be echoed as they are read by the parser. */
begin_unwind_frame ("fc builtin");
add_unwind_protect ((Function *)xfree, fn);
add_unwind_protect (unlink, fn);
add_unwind_protect (set_verbose_flag, (char *)NULL);
echo_input_at_read = 1;

retval = fc_execute_file (fn);
run_unwind_frame ("fc builtin");
```

The commands are printed to the standard error descriptor. As it turns, we can not control it via the standard interface.

But it is possible to `source` the file within the `$EDITOR`, then terminate the editor's process:

```
#!/bin/bash -
vim "$@"

if [[ "$(basename "$1")" =~ bash-fc-[0-9]+ ]]; then
  # Looks like edit-and-execute (C-x C-e)

  # The user has finished editing the temporary file.
  # It's time to evaluate the contents.
  source "$1"

  # Save current process ID for the subshell below.
  pid=$PID

  # The subshell helps to suppress the `Terminated` message.
  ( kill $pid >/dev/null 2>&1 )
fi
```

The commands will no longer be displayed after overriding the `$EDITOR` variable:

```
export EDITOR="/path/to/the-wrapper"
```